# URL encoding failed when using Bing Search

Tags: php, ajax, url, bing

I have a question here, I try to transfer a variable to my PHP script in order to retrieve data from Bing Search API.

I use the following AJAX code:

```
var bingquery = 'bingquery=' + $('#query').val();
    console.log(bingquery);

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "hw8.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: bingquery,
        success: function(jsondata){
            console.log('***Test for News Feeds***');
            console.log(jsondata); 
        }
        });
```

And my PHP is:

```
if (isset($_POST["bingquery"])){
    // Replace this value with your account key
    $accountKey = '***myaccountkey***';

    $WebSearchURL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/' + 'News?$format=json&Query=';

    $cred = sprintf('Authorization: Basic %s', base64_encode($accountKey . ":" . $accountKey) );

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => $cred
        )
    ));

    $request = $WebSearchURL . urlencode( '\'' . $_POST["bingquery"] . '\'');

//if I hard code the request URL here, it does work.

      $response = file_get_contents($request, 0, $context);

      echo $response;

    }
```

I wonder if there is something wrong with my URL encoding? Because the console says file_get_contents(0%27MYSYMBOL%27) fails, MYSYMBOL is the string I want in the search.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about the encoding at all, `urlencode` is supposed to make the input string url safe, and that is exactly what it is doing, `\` has special meaning in  a url and hence it is being encoded by the function.

**UPDATE**

You are adding up two strings, in PHP `.` is used to concatenate two strings, make the following changes,

```
$WebSearchURL = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/News'; 

$request = $WebSearchURL .'?Query='.urlencode($_POST["bingquery"]).'&$format=json;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I should have used . instead of +... Not so familiar with PHP.